# Nodejs Chat, all clients the same

Tags: node.js, sockets

Today I was going to play with NodeJS en I created this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNssI.png

Now, when a new client is comming he see`s not fbffbbfbfbfbfbffbbfbfbfbf. How is is possible when I send a socket with fbffbbfbfbfbfbffbbfbfbfbf its comming to show at all client pages? Just like a chat?

Code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var jade = require('jade');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set("view options", { layout: false });
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
app.listen(80);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(3872);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('send', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('update', { message: data.message});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a client sends something to the server, the `on('send')` function only sends the answer to this specific socket (`socket.emit`) where the event came from.

To send this message to all connected clients except the one who'd sent it, you have to use this code:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('update', { message: data.message});
```

Note that this excludes the socket, on which the broadcast is called. To send it really to all connected sockets use this (I think this is what you really want):

```
io.sockets.emit('update', { message: data.message});
```

(Both have to be called at the place, where you currently call `socket.emit(..)`)

Comment: `io.sockets.broadcast.emit` will send the event to every other socket. If you are looking to send a message/event to all, `io.sockets.emit`.